# Is there any way i can shorten this to one line?

Tags: python

This is the code, it just prints the users name once for each letter in their name.

```
name=input('Enter name ')
print((name+'\n')*len(name))
```

Comment: 1. Why would you want to do that? 2. Yes you can: `print((lambda name: (name+'\n')*len(name))(input('Enter name ')))`

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to make this one line.

Comment: Agreed. Do you know why you want to make it one line? It won't make it more performant or easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the walrus operator to assign the variable in a subexpression, so you can refer to it later.

```
print(((name := input('Enter name ')) + '\n') * len(name))
```